# Python 3.6: Mysql/Class/Inhertance connection issue

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to run the below code to connect to a database using python 3.6, I'm not sure I'm using Python correctly, I read in the config file and create and instance of the `Dao` class and pass the config details back to the parent class of `Dao` which is `Db`.

When I then go an try and open and close a connection on the `Dao` object it says that the `dbhost` isn't set.

Any help greatly appreciated.

### Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse.py", line 12, in <module>
    sources = daoObj.getSourceUrls()
  File "E:\classes\Dao.py", line 14, in getSourceUrls
    conn = super().open()
  File "E:\classes\Db.py", line 22, in open
    conn = pymysql.connect(dbhost, dbuser, dbpass, dbname);
NameError: name 'dbhost' is not defined
```

### parse.py

```
import configparser
from classes.Dao import Dao

# Load configuration settings
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("./config.ini")

# Create instance of database class
daoObj = Dao(config)

# Test database connection
daoObj.test()
```

### Dao.py

```
from classes.Db import Db

class Dao(Db):
    """Contains all SQL queries used for database interaction"""
    node = None

    def __init__(self, config):
        """Default constructor"""
        super().__init__(config)

    def getSourceUrls(self):
        conn = super().open()
        super().close(conn)
```

### Db.py

```
import pymysql

class Db:
    """Database connection class, handles all opening and closing of MySQL database connections."""
    dbuser = None
    dbpass = None
    dbhost = None
    dbname = None

    def __init__(self, config):
        """Default constructor"""
        # Assign the database login credentials
        dbuser = config["DB"]["USER"]
        dbpass = config["DB"]["PASS"]
        dbhost = config["DB"]["HOST"]
        dbname = config["DB"]["DATABASE"]

    def open(self):
        """Open database connection."""
        conn = None
        try:
            conn = pymysql.connect(dbhost, dbuser, dbpass, dbname);
        except pymysql.err.InternalError as e:
            print("Error connecting to database.")
        return conn

    def close(self, conn):
        """Close passed in database connection"""
        conn.close()
```

### config.ini

```
[DB]
USER=username
PASS=password
HOST=127.0.0.l
DATABASE=database
```

Comment: Ah, think I may have figured it, I need to add `self.` in front of the db variables I set and use in the `Db` class, seems to clear up this error.